# Android: Tesseract OCR not recognizing digits

Tags: java, android, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to capture digits from a card and convert the translated digits using tessaract ocr. I have set the whitelist to recognize only digits as shown but the conversion still returns inaccurate result.

```
baseApi.setImage(bitmap);
baseApi.setVariable(TessBaseApi.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, "0123456789");
recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
```

This is the image
[image]

Comment: Crop the region which you want to recognize and scan the cropped image.